# VBA Excel FileDialog return selecteditem as object

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a function in VBA for Excel to search for a file and ask the user to select of not found.

When I use the `application.filedialog` `filepicker` to select the file the `.selecteditem(1)` is returning as a string but I ideally need it returning as an object.

Is there a way to convert this or am I going the wrong way about it from the start?

```
Public myDir As String
Public newFilePath As String
Public FileSys As Object
Public myFolder

    Function LoadFileName(FileStart As String, FileType As String)
    newFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    myDir = newFilePath & "\Daily reports"
    ChDrive (Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 2))
    ChDir myDir
    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)        


    On Error GoTo FileNotFound

    Dim dteFile As Date
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim FileName As Object
    Dim strFileToOpen As Office.FileDialog

    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSysetmObject")

    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If FileSys.GetFile(objFile).DateCreated >= dteFile And UCase(Left(objFile.Name, 3)) = FileStart Then
        dteFile = FileSys.GetFile(objFile).DateCreated
        Set FileName = objFile
        End If
    Next

FileFound:
    fileConfirm = MsgBox("Is " & FileName.Name & " the report you wish to use?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)
    If fileConfirm = vbCancel Then
    End
    ElseIf fileConfirm = vbNo Then
    GoTo SelectFile
    ElseIf fileConfirm = vbYes Then
    Set LoadFileName = FileName
    Exit Function
    End If

FileNotFound:
    MsgBox "Unable to find most recent report." & vbCrLf & _
            "Please select the file you wish to use.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
SelectFile:
    Set strFileToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With strFileToOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Pleas select report to use."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel", "*." & FileType & "*"
    End With

    If strFileToOpen.Show = -1 Then
    FileName = strFileToOpen.SelectedItems(1)
    GoTo FileFound
    Else
    forceBreak = MsgBox("No file has been selected. Would you like to try again?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
        If forceBreak = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "The CQUIN daily patient list cannot be generated without both EPIC and CHEQS reports." & _
                "Please ensure these have been run and saved in the correct locations.", vbCritical
        End
        Else
        GoTo SelectFile
        End If

    End If


    End Function
```

Comment: What sort of object do you want the file's name to be converted to?

Comment: what "object" should it return? This object would differ with the filettype. If you need to open another Excel file use the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) with the filename you got from the dialog.

Comment: @YowE3K sorry I should have said. It's a file object.

Comment: It seems strange that you want a file object.  The most common thing in Excel is to want the file name, so I'm worried that your calling code is going to have to now take the object returned and use its `Name` or `Path` property - i.e. get back to the String you started with.  (But, as long as it works, I guess that's fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the solution on my own in the end. For those who want it, this is what I was missing:

I just needed to use `.GetFile`...

```
    If strFileToOpen.Show = -1 Then
    Set FileName = FileSys.GetFile(strFileToOpen.SelectedItems(1))
    GoTo FileFound
    Else
```