# For selected files retrieve the File type and file name

Tags: excel, vba

For each selected files, I am trying to retrieve the file type. Right now, I am able just to retrieve the file name. I currently have the following code here, but I was wondering if this too was possible. I am borrowing some code from donPablo (link here: [VBA Excel FileDialog return selecteditem as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778845/vba-excel-filedialog-return-selecteditem-as-object))

My code:

```
Dim fPath               As Variant
Dim FirstRow            As Long
Dim SelectedAutoCADfile As Integer
Dim vFiles              As Object
Dim objFolder         As Object              'This object allows you to create, delete, move or query a folder hierarchy.
Dim objFile           As Object              'This object allows you to create, delete, move or query a File

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set fPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog

.Title = "Please select the files"   'Title of Window Pop-up
.InitialFileName = Range("F12")      'This is the shortcut pathway
.AllowMultiSelect = True             'Allow the user to multiselect
.Filters.Clear                       'Clear all filters
.Filters.Add "DWG Files", "*.dwg"    'Only show AutoCAD files

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F12") = .SelectedItems(1)     'Document Pathway

FirstRow = Row + Sheet8.Range("D99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Available Row

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Create the File System Object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderSelected) 'Create the File System Folder

If .Show = True Then  'If the user selected some files

    For SelectedAutoCADfile = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count 'For each of the files the user selected

       Sheet7.Cells(FirstRow, 4) = Dir(.SelectedItems(SelectedAutoCADfile)) 'Writes the filename to each cell
       Cells(Row, 5) = objFile.Type                'Places the FileType in this column

       FirstRow = FirstRow + 1                                                   
       'Go to next available row
      Next
    Next
   'Go to next file
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, and quite trivially, using the Scripting.File object:

```
Dim fDialog ' your code doesn't specify which type this should be
Dim fPath As Variant
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set fPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog
    .Title = "Please select the files"
    .InitialFileName = Range("F12")
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "DWG Files", "*.dwg"
End With

If Not fDialog.Show Then Exit Sub ' if within a Function, then set the function value and Exit Function instead of Exit Sub

' Not sure why you need to do this here
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F12") = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)

Dim nextRow As Long
nextRow = FirstRow = Row + Sheet8.Range("D99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (via Tools -> References...)

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fle As Scripting.File
Dim selectedFilename as Variant
For Each selectedFilename In fDialog.SelectedItems
    Set fle = fso.GetFile(selectedFilename)
    Sheet7.Cells(nextRow, 4) = fle.Name
    Sheet7.Cells(nextRow, 5) = fle.Type
    Debug.Print fle.ParentFolder.Path ' Prints the parent folder's path to the Debug window
    nextRow = nextRow + 1
Next
```

---

### References

- [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) -- [GetFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfile-method) method
- [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object) -- [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-property-filesystemobject-object), [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-property-filesystemobject-object), and [ParentFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/parentfolder-property) properties
- [Folder object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folder-object) -- [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/path-property-filesystemobject-object) property